# Math symbols as acronym

Tags: symbols, amsmath, acronyms

I need to add the math symbol \alpha in my acronym list, but I get the listed error message.

### Example text

```
\ac{$alpha$} was identified with the following equation.
\begin{align}  
\alpha & = \frac{(22.4 \cdot \frac{273 + T}{273}) \cdot 10^6}{M_{mol} \cdot 10^3} \cdot \frac{W_{Filter}}{V_{Filter}}
\end{align}
Where,
\begin{table}[H]
\begin{tabular}{l|ll}
\ac{\alpha} & conversion coefficient & (-) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

### Acro list

```
\begin{acronym}[MPC]
\acro{$\alpha$}{conversion coefficient}
\end{acronym}
```

### Error message

```
LaTeX Error: Option clash for package textcomp -> See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.51         \UndeclareTextCommand
                                  {\textpertenthousand}{T1} 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 37000 strings out of 480906
 685527 string characters out of 5908280
 1275407 words of memory out of 5000000
 51971 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 536769 words of font info for 33 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 1143 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 71i,1n,117p,431b,221s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s
```

---

### Preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,fleqn,twoside,openright]{memoir}    % Openright aabner kapitler paa hoejresider (openany begge)


\usepackage{emptypage}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% PAKKER %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

% ¤¤ Oversaettelse og tegnsaetning ¤¤ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 
% Input-indkodning af tegnsaet (UTF8)

\usepackage[english]{babel}                 
% Dokumentets sprog / English language/hyphenation

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    
% Output-indkodning af tegnsaet (T1)

\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}           
% Justering af elementer
    
    
            
% ¤¤ Figurer og tabeller (floats) ¤¤ %
\usepackage{graphicx}                       
% Haandtering af eksterne billeder (JPG, PNG, PDF)

\usepackage{multirow}                       
% Fletning af raekker og kolonner (\multicolumn og \multirow)

\usepackage{colortbl}                       
% Farver i tabeller (fx \columncolor, \rowcolor og \cellcolor)

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}             
% Definer farver med \definecolor. Se mere: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors

\usepackage{flafter}                        
% Soerger for at floats ikke optraeder i teksten foer deres reference

\usepackage{float}
% Places the float at precisely the location in the LATEX code

% H: Places the float at precisely the location in the LATEX code
% h: Place the float here, i.e., approximately at the same point it occurs in the source text (however, not exactly at the spot)
% t: Position at the top of the page.
% b: Position at the bottom of the page.
% p: Put on a special page for floats only.
% !: Override internal parameters LATEX uses for determining "good" float positions.

\let\newfloat\relax                         
% Justering mellem float-pakken og memoir

\usepackage{float}                          
% Muliggoer eksakt placering af floats, f.eks. \begin{figure}[H]

%\usepackage{eso-pic}                       
% Tilfoej billedekommandoer paa hver side

\usepackage{wrapfig}                        
% Indsaettelse af figurer omsvoebt af tekst. \begin{wrapfigure}{Placering}{Stoerrelse}

%\usepackage{multicol}                      
% Muliggoer tekst i spalter

%\usepackage{rotating}                      
% Rotation af tekst med \begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}

% ¤¤ Matematik mm. ¤¤
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       
% Avancerede matematik-udvidelser

\usepackage{mathtools}                      
% Andre matematik- og tegnudvidelser

\usepackage{textcomp}                       
% Symbol-udvidelser (f.eks. promille-tegn med \textperthousand )

\usepackage{siunitx}                        
% Flot og konsistent praesentation af tal og enheder med \si{enhed} og \SI{tal}{enhed}

\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}       
% Opsaetning af \SI og decimalseparator

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}              
% Kemi-pakke til flot og let notation af formler, f.eks. \ce{Fe2O3}

\usepackage{chemformula}

\usepackage{rsphrase}                   
% Kemi-pakke til RS-saetninger, f.eks. \rsphrase{R1}

% SI Units
\usepackage{siunitx}
%\SI{4,186}{\joule} tal med enhed
%\ce{H_2S_{(aq)}} kemisk formel


% ¤¤ Referencer og kilder ¤¤ %
\usepackage[danish]{varioref}               
% Muliggoer bl.a. krydshenvisninger med sidetal (\vref)

\usepackage[round]{natbib}                          
% Udvidelse med naturvidenskabelige citationsmodeller

\usepackage{xr}                         
% Referencer til eksternt dokument med \externaldocument{<NAVN>}

% ¤¤ Litteraturlisten ¤¤ %
%\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}                 
% Definerer de 6 parametre ved Harvard henvisning (bl.a. parantestype og seperatortegn)
\bibliographystyle{0.Litteraturliste/harvard}           
% Udseende af litteraturlisten.




% ¤¤ Misc. ¤¤ %
\usepackage{listings}                       
% Placer kildekode i dokumentet med \begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}

\usepackage{lipsum}                         
% Dummy text \lipsum[..]

\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}          
% Muliggoer enkelt konfiguration af lister

\usepackage{pdfpages}                       
% Goer det muligt at inkludere pdf-dokumenter med kommandoen \includepdf[pages={x-y}]{fil.pdf}  
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6                 
% Muliggoer inkludering af pdf dokumenter, af version 1.6 og hoejere
\pretolerance=2500                          
% Justering af afstand mellem ord (hoejt tal, mindre orddeling og mere luft mellem ord)

% Kommentarer og rettelser med \fxnote. Med 'final' i stedet for 'draft' udloeser hver note en error i den faerdige rapport.
\usepackage[footnote,draft,danish,silent,nomargin]{fixme}       


%%%% BRUGERDEFINEREDE INDSTILLINGER %%%%

% ¤¤ Marginer ¤¤ %
\setlrmarginsandblock{3.5cm}{2.5cm}{*}      
% \setlrmarginsandblock{Indbinding}{Kant}{Ratio}

\setulmarginsandblock{2.5cm}{3.0cm}{*}      
% \setulmarginsandblock{Top}{Bund}{Ratio}

\checkandfixthelayout                       
% Oversaetter vaerdier til brug for andre pakker

%   ¤¤ Afsnitsformatering ¤¤ %
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                 
% Stoerrelse af indryk

\setlength{\parskip}{2mm}                   
% Afstand mellem afsnit ved brug af double Enter

\linespread{1,1}                            
% Linie afstand


% ¤¤ Dybde af overskrifter ¤¤ %
\setsecnumdepth{subsubsection}                  
% Dybden af nummerede overkrifter (part/chapter/section/subsection)

\settocdepth{section}                   
% Dybden af overskrifter vist i indholdsfortegnelsen

% ¤¤ Lister ¤¤ %
\setlist{
  topsep=0pt,                               
  % Vertikal afstand mellem tekst og listen
  itemsep=-1ex,                             
  % Vertikal afstand mellem items
} 


% ¤¤ Visuelle referencer ¤¤ %
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}           
% Danner klikbare referencer (hyperlinks) i dokumentet.
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,              
% Opsaetning af farvede hyperlinks (interne links, citeringer og URL)
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor = black,
    urlcolor = black
}



% ¤¤ Opsaetning af figur- og tabeltekst ¤¤ %
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\itshape}   
% Opsaetning af tekstdelen ('Figur' eller 'Tabel')

\captiontitlefont{\small}                   
% Opsaetning af nummerering

\captiondelim{. }                           
% Seperator mellem nummerering og figurtekst

\captionstyle{\centering}                   
% Justering/placering af figurteksten (centreret = \centering, venstrejusteret = \raggedright)

\captionwidth{\linewidth}                   
% Bredden af figurteksten

\hangcaption                                
% Venstrejusterer flere-liniers figurtekst under hinanden

\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}          
% Afstand under figurteksten



% ¤¤ Opsaetning af listings ¤¤ %
\definecolor{commentGreen}{RGB}{34,139,24}
\definecolor{stringPurple}{RGB}{208,76,239}

\lstset{language=Matlab,                    
% Sprog
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,        
    % Opsaetning af teksten
    keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,     
    % Noegleord at fremhaeve
              end,break,return,case,
              switch,function},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              
    % Opsaetning af noegleord
    commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},      
    % Opsaetning af kommentarer
    stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},       
    % Opsaetning af strenge
    showstringspaces=false,                 
    % Mellemrum i strenge enten vist eller blanke
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,        
    % Linjenumre
    extendedchars=true,                     
    % Tillader specielle karakterer
    columns=flexible,                       
    % Kolonnejustering
    breaklines, breakatwhitespace=true,     
    % Bryd lange linjer
}



%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% TABLE OF CONTENTS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{titletoc} 
% Required for manipulating the table of contents
\addto\captionsdanish{
    \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendix}
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of contens}    
    \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendix}
    \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendix}
    %\renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}                
    % Skriver "Kapitel" foran kapitlerne i indholdsfortegnelsen
    \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}           
    % Skriver "Appendiks" foran appendiks i indholdsfortegnelsen
}















%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% KAPITEL DESIGN %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{transparent}
% ¤¤ Kapiteludssende ¤¤ %
\definecolor{applegreen}{rgb}{0.55, 0.71, 0.0}      
% Definerer en farve til brug til kapiteludseende

\newif\ifchapternonum

%%%%%%% Definerer kapiteludseende frem til ...
\makechapterstyle{jenor}{                   
  \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{db}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont\raggedright}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{0.7in}{0in}\selectfont\color{black}\transparent{0.6}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par} 
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}   


%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% ... her %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\chapterstyle{jenor}                        
% Valg af kapiteludseende - Google 'memoir chapter styles' for alternativer


% ¤¤ Sidehoved/sidefod ¤¤ %

\makepagestyle{Uni}                         
% Definerer sidehoved og sidefod udseende frem til ...
\makepsmarks{Uni}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{subsubsection}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\nouppercaseheads                                           
% Ingen Caps oenskes

%\makeevenhead{Uni}{Gruppe B131}{}{\leftmark}               
% Lige siders sidehoved (\makeevenhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddhead{Uni}{\rightmark}{}{Aalborg University}     
% Ulige siders sidehoved (\makeoddhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeevenfoot{Uni}{\thepage}{}{}                            
% Lige siders sidefod (\makeevenfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddfoot{Uni}{}{}{\thepage}                             
% Ulige siders sidefod (\makeoddfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeheadrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}                       
% Tilfoejer en streg under sidehovedets indhold
\makefootrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{1mm}                  
% Tilfoejer en streg under sidefodens indhold

\copypagestyle{Unichap}{Uni}                                
% Sidehoved defineres som blank på kapitelsider
\makeoddhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeheadrule{Unichap}{\textwidth}{0pt}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{Unichap}                           % Den ny style vaelges til at gaelde for chapters
                                                            % ... her
                                                            
\pagestyle{Uni}                                             % Valg af sidehoved og sidefod (benyt "plain" for ingen sidehoved/fod)


%%%% EGNE KOMMANDOER %%%%

% ¤¤ Billede hack ¤¤ %                                      % Indsaet figurer nemt med \figur{Stoerrelse}{Fil}{Figurtekst}{Label}
\newcommand{\figur}[4]{
        \begin{figure}[H] \centering
            \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{billeder/#2}
            \caption{#3}
            \label{#4}
        \end{figure} 
}

% ¤¤ Specielle tegn ¤¤ %
\newcommand{\decC}{^{\circ}\text{C}}
\newcommand{\dec}{^{\circ}}
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}


%%%% ORDDELING %%%%
\hyphenation{In-te-res-se e-le-ment}

\usepackage{gensymb}

%"x"

\usepackage{dirtytalk}

%{accents}


\usepackage{url}

\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{diagbox}

\usepackage{adjustbox}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\sisetup{inter-unit-product=\ensuremath{{}\cdot{}}}


\usepackage{tgpagella}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{comment}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{parskip}


\usepackage{soul}% for the underlining 
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{dblfloatfix}

\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{stix}

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{acronym} 
\usepackage{mhchem}
```

---

Hope somebody know how to fix this situation

Comment: Your error message references `\usepackage{textcomp}`, which you should not need on a reent distribution. What happens if you remove it?

Comment: When removing \usepackage{textcomp} the error message changed to:
 <to be read again> 
                   \alpha 
l.512 \AC@undonewlabel{acro:$\alpha $}
                                      
The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
not appear between \csname and \endcsname

Comment: One thing that jumps out at me is that this MWE have a lot of duplicated, redundant and conflicting packages. Several redefine `\alpha`. I have no idea which of them you really need. I would suggest you start with a fresh preamble, start by adding only the packages you need for your document to compile, and then back the others you actually want, or your publisher requires, one by one.

Comment: In the future, it’d be better if you post a minimal example with only the packages needed to duplicate the bug.

Answer (score 1):

According to section 2.3 of the `acronym` manual, you should give this acronym a name that works as a `\csname` and use the optional short-name parameter, such as:

```
\acro{alpha}[$\alpha$]{conversion coefficient}
```

Additionally, you have many duplicated, redundant and conflicting packages in your preamble, and I would recommend cleaning it out.